# Integer not working with an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I am making a text based game, and I am experimenting with different ways of making the storyline of the game progress. (Im sorry if this is semi-hard to follow, I am new to this website, and still fairly new to Java, I'm making this for a class project)

One of the ways I am trying is by increasing a value (In this case LevelNum) by one, and whenever a number not equal to zero is displayed it will set the text of jLabel1 to whatever the text is.

I am trying to do this by using an if statement as shown here:

```
if(LevelNum == 0) {
                jLabel1.setText(StoryData.LevelOne);
            }
```

The increase of LevelNum is done like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    LevelNum += 1;
                    System.out.println(LevelNum);

            }
```

(The System.out was just to check to see if it was increasing the number)

The problem I am running into is that no matter what the value of jLabel1 is, the text never changes, and I dont know why.

The whole code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/JSX6urFT

The StoryData is a seperate class within in my text document, and the individual strings look like this: `static String LevelOne = "Level one test";`

Here is all the code related to LevelNum:

```
public class DemoGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private static int LevelNumBackUp = 0;
private static int LevelNum = 0;
public JTextArea jLabel1;
public JTextField jText1;
public JButton jButton1;
public JButton jButton2;
public JButton jButton3;
public JButton jButton4;
public JButton jButtonStart;
public JTextArea jTextAreaStart;
public JButton jButtonCredits;
public JButton jButtonReturn;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int LevelNum = 0;
    int LevelNumBackUp = 0;
```

Comment: Please post the relevant pieces of code, such as definition of LevelNum, as well as whether or not the action is actually called.

Comment: I added in the code for the LevelNum, the only reason I didnt was because Last time i put too much code I got yelled at for having too much code, which was why I opted to link the a pastebin with all the code

Comment: You only set the label text once when you initialize your GUI, before the button is ever shown or clicked. You never modify it again. This is why it doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep level changing code in actionPerformed.
Try this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    LevelNum += 1;
                    System.out.println(LevelNum);
                    // Introduction
                    if (LevelNum == 1) {
                        jLabel1.setText("level1");
                    }
                    if (LevelNum == 2) {
                        jLabel1.setText("level2");
                    }
                    if (LevelNum == 3) {
                        jLabel1.setText("level3");
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

After the value of the label changed, try to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` to update your Userinterface

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the full code, the part which increments LevelNum is in the following block:

```
jButton3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    LevelNum += 1;
                    System.out.println(LevelNum);

                }
            });
```

Then, down below, you have this code:

```
if(LevelNum == 1) {
                jLabel1.setText(StoryData.LevelOne);
            }
```

Let's walk through the code the way a computer would. When we get to that first block, we add a new ActionListener. However, we do not execute the actionPerformed method immediately, so LevelNum is still what it was previously. Later on, we get to the if statement, but LevelNum has not been incremented.

When the ActionListener is triggered, and the actionPerformed method executes, it increments LevelNum and then prints the new LevelNum, but it does NOT change jLabel1 because there is no code telling it to do so.

It looks like what you want to do is update jLabel1 inside the actionPerformed method.